# log in to facebook using solely a URL

Tags: php, facebook, url

could I log in using only a URL and PHP parameters?

like http://facebook.com?login=whatever&password=whatever

Comment: you should use the facebook APIs. What for are they building such technologies? for you people to find a way to login directly? isnt it? hahaha lol. lmao.

Comment: i want a bookmark button to log me in....

Comment: click on the remember me option to that dude. :P

Comment: Is it even a programming question?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After wondering a bit why on Earth would you want to do that, I chose to answer blindly. So if you use a browser (and not a script), you could paste this in your address bar:

```
javascript:document.write('
<form id="l" method="post"
action="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1">
<input type="hidden" id="e" name="email">
<input type="hidden" name="pass" id="p"></form>');

function g(x){
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

g('e').value='USERNAME';
g('p').value="PASSWORD";
g('l').submit();
```

Replace USERNAME and PASSWORD with your own Email / Password and it will log you in.

Comment: adding password in plain text is NOT recommended in all circumstances. It can easily be captured.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You have to go through Facebook Connect API.

Comment: what's the URL passed by the login form then?

Comment: @tekknolagi: See this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement login using facebook, check the developer documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)